# Currently I get the result of my query but I want to get count of records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get a `count` of my query in a number currently it shows all records

Controller:

```
 public function fetchCounts(){
    $Result = $this->receivedModel->vehicleFreight($this->session->userdata('user_branch'));
    }
```

Model:

```
public function vehicleFreight($branch_id)  
        {  
             $this->db->select('*');
             $this->db->from('truck_freight');
             $this->db->where('truck_freight_status','truck_freight');
             $this->db->where('fr_memo_to',$branch_id);

            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }
```

How can I use `count()` in my query.
In my data base I have 3 records.

Comment: Or maybe `query->count()` ?

Comment: Or you can do **$this->db->select('count(*)');**

Comment: you can use `count($query->result())` OR `$query->num_rows()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this 
**Model**

```
public function vehicleFreight($branch_id)  
        {  
             $this->db->select('count(*)');
             $this->db->from('truck_freight');
             $this->db->where('truck_freight_status','truck_freight');
             $this->db->where('fr_memo_to',$branch_id);

            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to get count

```
1 . echo count($query->result()); 


2 . echo $query->num_rows();

3 . You can use `count(*)` in `select` statement
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the count of fetched records,

```
$data = $query->result();
echo count($data); // use this as per your requirements
return $data;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following function to return number of results.

```
return $this->db->count_all_results();
```

This should be used in place of get()

```
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Please check [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

Answer (score 1):

change the code as follows:

```
$results = $query->result();
$count = count($results);
return $count
```